# C++. Do type casted arrays need to be memory managed?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

The code looks like this:

```
std::string str = (char *) xmlTextReaderReadString(*xml);
```

Memory management for str works fine. str makes a deep copy of the character array.

What is being made when typecasting is what I am worried about. xmlTextReaderReadString is returning a typedefed unsigned char * or how they defined it an (xmlChar*).

I couldn't find a viable question on stack overflow, but if you did, just link it and I'll delete this post.

So forth with an example like this:

```
xmlTextReaderGetAttribute (*xml, (xmlChar*)"type"))
```

Do I need to memory manage the typecasted "type"

Comment: what is `xmlTextReaderReadString` returning? read its documentation.

Comment: @DanielA.White I changed the post to fit what you said. It returns a type-defed unsigned char * or how they defined it an (xmlChar*).

Comment: It depends on what type of result `xmlTextReader()` gives.  If it returns a raw pointer to dynamically allocated memory, then that memory needs to be managed.   If it returns a class type that has an `operator char *()` that allows the conversion, then it depends on how that class manages memory.   If it is something else (e.g. a pointer to another type that cannot be safely converted to `char *`) then the behavior of the assignment is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. In conjunction with the answer, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to call `xmlFree()` on the returned value from `xmlTextReaderReadString`, after building your `std::string`.

I never used that library, but a google search turned up the answer in seconds.

It also has nothing to do with the cast. You got a value, you can use it, but you need to free it afterward. If you use the value, in the meantime to build a `std::string`, the `std::string` will manage its own copy, you still need to manage yours.

The second API you use is also labelled

> The string must be deallocated by the caller

but that applies to the returned value, not to `"type"`. This one is a literal that should not be freed.

http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/yoz/libxml2-2.7.3/doc/html/libxml-xmlreader.html

Comment: Thanks. How did I miss that. 

I also edited the question to ask another question with a slightly different example. Also, isn't the typecasted variable made on a different memory location though? I don't know how that works